# Running upstart jobs as root but works like unprivileged users

Tags: permissions, upstart

I Have a application that need to run like root user, but I need that the enviroment, will be of an unprivileged user.

For example:

ipython, start by root (ubuntu) user; but I need that cann't run code with commands using sudo.

So, I believe that, maybe; if I run the job like root, but...HOW, only works for a "x" user.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo works both ways, root can also act as a regular user
`sudo -u userName -g groupName`
I haven't used it but it looks like gksudo has the same functionality for desktop top applications

Comment: Thanks!... I did it, your answer; but not works...

The solution was add; `root    ALL = NOEXEC: /usr/bin/sudo` in visudo.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider making your application a [startup service](https://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts).

Here is a [good guide](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html) to get you started.

Comment: IM application and runs as a service; which is launched by the root user. But I do not want my users to gain privileges (eg sudo) to use.